# Default file location for inserted pictures in PowerPoint 365 and Excel 365

Tags: microsoft-word, default-settings

Whenever I open a Microsoft 365's document for the first time, click any image and select to replace it with a file stored locally:

[image]

Word opens up to *This PC > Pictures*. I need to change to my default location each time after Word, Excel or PowerPoint restart.

Is there anyway to prevent it and change *This PC > Pictures* to some other default (mine) location?

I have tried to browse settings of Microsoft 365, but I found nothing. I also tried to search the Internet in general or Super User in particular, but also to no avail. I found [this answer](https://superuser.com/q/668136/156554) and [this one](https://superuser.com/q/1327831/156554), but both of them says about something else and doesn't answer my question.

**EDIT**: *I know how to change default file location for images in Word 365. I am asking how to do this for PowerPoint 365 and Excel 365. Method for Word 365 does not work in PowerPoint 365 and Excel 365 because there is no "File Location" button in the corresponding configuration section for these two Microsoft 365 components.*

Answer (score 4):

Do this for Word :

- Click *File > Options*
- Click Advanced
- Scroll down to the General section
- Click on File Locations...
- Click to select Images
- Click the button Modify...
- Select your pictures folder
- Click twice OK.

For more information with screenshots, see the article
[How to Change the Default “Insert Picture” Location in Microsoft Word](https://www.howtogeek.com/265902/how-to-change-the-default-insert-picture-location-in-microsoft-word/).

For other products than Word, the simplest solution
for loading images is to drag-and-drop them from Explorer.

Comment: I know your solution and (unfortunately) it works in / for Word 365 only. PowerPoint 365 has "Show add-in user interface errors" and "Always open encrypted files in this app" checkbox only and no "File Locations" button in _File → Options → Advanced → General_. And Excel 365 has a lot of configuration settings in this section but also no "File Locations" button. I've setup my own default location for pictures in Word 365 (using your method, already known to me) and it works in Word 365 only. Excel 365 and PowerPoint 365 still starts in _This PC → Pictures_ folder.

Comment: Sorry for not mentioning this in my question in first place. I have edited it to lift off possible confusion. Thanks.

Comment: My own solution for loading images is to drag-and-drop them from Explorer. This always works.

Comment: Jesus! :) It's that simple? :)